# Writing a stream cipher for DCPU-16, which should I focus on given it's limitations?

Tags: cryptography, dcpu-16, stream-cipher

For fun I am writing a stream cipher in assembly for the [DCPU-16](http://0x10c.com/doc/dcpu-16.txt) (the fictional CPU for the game [0x10<sup>c</sup>](http://0x10c.com/)). The processor only has 16 bit registers and it runs at 100 Khz. However, for now, memory access and things like multiplication and division are obscenely fast (A `DIV` using two indirect memory accesses only takes 5 cycles).

With those kinds of constraints, what would my best option be? I was considering RC4, however I am concerned that other people using my code will not use it correctly and we could have another WEP disaster on our hands. I feel that I will need to do something more complicated than RC4 so to protect other programmers from themselves, however I am concerned about algorithms that use magic numbers or precomputed tables that are expecting 8 bit bytes as the smallest unit instead of 16 bit words.

Comment: *"however I am concerned that other people using my code will not use it correctly and we could have another WEP disaster"* - That is true of any cipher.

Comment: Hmm, that is very true. @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft write up something similar to your comment as a answer and I will give you the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "however I am concerned that other people using my code will not use it correctly and we could have another WEP disaster"

That would be true of any cipher - RC4 should work just fine.

You might also want to check out the [eStream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESTREAM) ciphers.  In particular, [Grain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grain_%28cipher%29) claims to be *"designed for restricted hardware environments."*  I have no experience with it, though, so I don't know how easy it would be to implement in software.